How to detect esc while input in python
I am doing an input script in python, and I want to detect the ESc button is pressedwhile input. I tried to to use keyoard detector but it does not work. Here is what I did:
import msvcrt

# validating input
def enteringMessage(message):
    while True:

        try:
            # Convert the input to an integer
            message = int(message)

            # Check if the value is within the range
            assert 1 <= message <= 24
            return message  # Return the valid value
        except ValueError:
            # Handle non-numerical input
            message = input('What day is it [1,24] ?\n')
        except AssertionError:
            # Handle out-of-range values
            message = input('What day is it [1,24] ?\n')

aborted = False

while not aborted:
    day = enteringMessage(input('What day is it [1,24] ?\n'))
    if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch() == b'\x1b':
        aborted = True
        break
    humorOftheDay = 'xxxxx'  #I fixed this for simplification purpose
    print("Joke of December ", day, ": ")
    print(humorOftheDay)

I tried to use libary msvcrt to detect and modify the aborted variable to stop the input loop, but when I ran in terminal, it does not work.
Code written in Python, version 3.9
Can you help me out. Thank you in advance.

With msvcrt.getch you'll have to implement your own input function to deal with key presses (including special ones such as backspaces) and translating them into a string of characters.
If you can install the pynput library, an easier approach would be to listen to the on_press keyboard event with a handler that terminates the process if the key of the event is ESC:
import os
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        os._exit(0)

keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press).start()

while True:
    print(f'You entered: {input("Enter something: ")}')


Thank you. I have sucessfully integrated you solution to my work. I will close the issue here.
